# How to find a specific pattern into a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a pdf reader in python, I already got the pdf read and

I got a list with the content of the pdf and I want now to give me back the numbers with eleven characters, like 123.456.789-33 or 124.323.432.33

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import re
reader = PdfReader(r"\\abcdacd.pdf")

number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
page = reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
num = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
print(num)
```

here's the output:

```
['01', '01', '2000', '26', '12', '2022', '04483203983', '044', '832', '039', '83', '20210002691450', '5034692', '79', '2020', '8', '24', '0038', '1', '670', '03', '2', '14', '2', '14', '1', '670', '03', '2', '14', '2', '14', '1', '1', '8', '21', '1']
```

If someone could help me, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: What is the expected format of the 11-digit entity? What should happen to `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.1`, for example?

Comment: I wouldn't like to get this number, in my output I'd simply like to recognize a format with 11 digits and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change regex pattern to the following (to match groups of digits):

```
s = 'text text 123.456.789-33 or 124.323.432.33 text or 12323112333 or even 123,231,123,33 '
num = re.findall(r'\d{3}[.,]?\d{3}[.,]?\d{3}[.,-]?\d{2}', s)
print(num)
```

---

```
['123.456.789-33', '124.323.432.33', '12323112333', '123,231,123,33']
```

Comment: It worked but I still have some questions, like if in the pdf file has 123.231.123-33 or 12323112333 or even 123,231,123,33 it would read the same way?

Comment: @Carlos.Correia, no, it will require a more extended pattern, see my update

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
\b(?:\d[.-]*){11}\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yJZplU/2)

---

```py
import re

s = '''\
123.456.789-33
124.323.432.33
111-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'''

pat = re.compile(r'\b(?:\d[.-]*){11}\b')
for m in pat.findall(s):
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
123.456.789-33
124.323.432.33
111-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
```